# Using an admin account as the sender for an action rule instead of site:current-user

Tags: 7, rules

I am using a reaction rule that triggers, when a new user is registered. This rule sends a private message to a role ( service-role ).

The sender of the message is the actual logged in user - in this case the user that was just created, the new user.

I want the sender to be the admin but I have no change to select the admin the the data-selection field. How can I archive any other user that the actual logged in user?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't find what you're looking for, you could try to use the <kbd>Switch to the direct input mode</kbd> button and then enter the userid of the admin.

That's a kind of "hardcoding" one may say, but at least it is "a" way to use what you're asking for.

Be aware: that userid to be entered can be an identifier of just any userid (so if the userid entered is not a user who is "***the admin***" (as in your question), that should work too.

Comment: Thank you, yes there is another display, but it will not change my question. Maybe I have to create a condition to reach the depth I want. Unfortunably I don't know the condition that is necessary.

Comment: @Katasun : What do you mean by "***yes there is another display***, which display do you mean? Also, why did you write "***it will not change my question***"? Moreover, I don't see how adding whatever "condition" would help you. Please try explaining your prior comment again.

Comment: Could you please verify my answer. If you are in the direct input mode, please type in a valid user id. This will be the sender of the message then.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to select the wanted sender User by typing in the USER ID when the form is in direct input mode. To get to this "direct input mode", use the button "switch to direct input mode", as shown here:

[image]

After doing so, the form will look like so:

[image]

So in the end, the result of doing so is that if you read your private messages, then the sender is not the new user anymore, but the user you selected by ID manually (as shown in the above form).

Comment: Please review my attempt to further improve your answer (eg I also integrated the 2nd screenprint you linked to, but which didn't show up yet). Feel free to further adapt/refine, or just perform a rollback to the original version of your answer if you don't like my edit at all. OK?

Comment: Sorry for my short answer. I can't find the image anymore. All I like to add is that it is not only working for the id number one, the admin. You can choose any valid user id, but you have to be in direct edit mode.

Comment: I hope other users can use this if they want to send a private messages to a role and need a specifiy sender. In my case people with the role service recieve the message and in case of technical problems reply directly to the admin and not to the new user.

Comment: About the image you cannot find anymore: the first version of your answer included a hyperlink to a 2nd screenprint (without showiing the screenprint). My edit only transformed that in the (first) image shown in your answer now (it's the same image). And yes it's working for any userid you'd enter (cfr the "be aware" in my own answer for more details).